# Proof by induction on contraction mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Let $k:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous, and $x(t) = \int_0^t k(t,s)x(s)ds$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Not let $Tx(t) = \int_0^t k(t,s)x(s)ds$ and suppose $sup_{0 \leq t, s \leq 1}|k(t,s)|= M$. Assuming $Tx$ is a continous function for $x$ continous,and letting $T^{(n)}$ be the n-fold composition of $T$ with itself, show by induction for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$ we have $$|T^{(n)}x(t)-T^{(n)}y(t)|\leq \frac{M^n t^n}{n!} sup_{0 \leq s \leq 1}|x(s)-y(s)$$

Now I have got stuck even on the simplest case, for $n=1$, I have:

$$|Tx(t) - Ty(t)| = |\int_0^t k(t,s)x(s)ds - \int_0^t k(t,s)y(s)ds|$$
$$= |\int_0^t k(t,s)(x(s)-y(s))ds|$$
$$\leq |M\int_0^t(x(s) - y(s)ds|$$

But I can't find out where the $t$ which should be in the equation comes from.

I'm also struggling with the induction part:

Assuming the statement is true for $n = k$, i.e. $$|T^{(k)}x(t)-T^{(k)}y(t)|\leq \frac{M^k t^k}{k!} sup_{0 \leq s \leq 1}|x(s)-y(s)|$$

Then for $n = k+1$,

$$|T{(k+1)}x(t) - T^{(k+1)}y(t)| = |T \circ T^k x(s) - T \circ T^k y(s)|$$
$$ \leq T(\frac{M^k t^k}{k!} sup_{0 \leq s \leq 1}|x(s)-y(s)|$$

Then I am not sure how to take the $T$ of the above function.

All hints and tips much appreciated thanks

Comment: The $t$ comes from the length of the interval over which you integrate: $\int_a^b |f|\le |b-a| \sup |f|$

Comment: Ahh yes of course! Thanks Thomas.How about for the inductive step? How can I take $T$ of a function which is not in the original format?

Comment: Just apply the result (literally) for $n=1$ to $T^nx -T^ny$, or the result for $n$ to $Tx-Ty$ (to get a first estimate by, e.g., $\le t^n/n! M^k |Tx(s)-Ty(s)|$, then apply the result once more. You basically did that already, but left out the literal application of that step.